# Should the number of the object "colleges" follow the number of the subject?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, grammaticality-in-context, countability

In this sentence:

> We lost contact since we entered **colleges**.

Should "colleges" be in the plural form, since these two persons entered two different colleges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We lost contact since we entered colleges.

No, that is incorrect. A simple answer is that "colleges" should be changed to "college". However because they are different colleges it's perhaps still missing something.

Alternatives:

> We lost contact after we (each/both) went away to college.

"went away" implies different colleges.

or

> We lost contact after high school. I went to Harvard, and she to Yale.

That's clear.

In any case, "we entered" does have a connotation that "we" did something together, and so you are right about it being ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I do not disagree with Sam's answer, but **go to college** in US English is frequently a description of a cultural rite of passage rather of a physical journey and thus treated as a fixed phrase. Use of the plural within that phrase is not idiomatic in the US. I agree that keeping **college** singular can sometimes leave an ambiguity about whether one college is meant or more than one college is meant. To indicate multiple colleges, you would not say **go to colleges** but rather say **go to different colleges**, which makes clear that you are not using **go to college** in its sense of a rite of passage.